# Android native spinner RTL using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, android-spinner

I am using jquery mobile 1.3.0 RTL, which I have downloaded from a link. RTL works fine for all the form components except spinner/drop down in android. For drop down it uses the device's native control. It works perfectly on iOS devices but not in android devices it comes in LTR still. I tried to disable the native spinner by using the following javascript code.

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
   $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
   if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
     $("select").attr("data-native-menu","true");
   }
   else{
      $("select").attr("data-native-menu","false");
      $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
   }
});
```

The above code disables the native drop down and jquery mobile designs the drop down selection list. If I have below 10 items in the list it shows properly and it works fine but not for larger lists (Scroll is not working and data is not rendered properly in the list). I would like to go with the native spinner. For more specific, If I am accessing my application through google chrome browser when my language is arabic the spinner is working proper but not in the default Internet explorer. Because hybrid application uses only the web view of internet explorer. Is there any configurations specific to android applications?

Comment: For spinners i use spin js  as you have more control when you want to start it and close it -- http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which I was using for RTL is working fine. I have tested the drop down with english text. Whenever I changed my language to arabic the android native drop down alignment was changed. Thanks for your reply "Tasos"